# DC.JS scatterplot chart selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, scatter-plot, dc.js

[image]

Hi, I am using dc.js.

I can not understand how can I get data for building the tooltip shown in the screenshot.

How do I get the selected items in the event handler brush.on ( 'brushend.foo', function () {}) ?

This is my handler to draw the tooltip:

```
var brush = this.chart.brush();
    brush.on('brushend.foo', function() {
      let selection = self.chart.select('.extent');


      let tooltipValues = {
        maxProbability:  '-',
        minProbability: '-',
        minImpact: '-',
        maxImpact: '-',
      }
      selection.on('mousemove', function(){
        selection.on
          div.transition()
           .duration(200)
           .style("opacity", 1);

         div.html(
           `
           <div> Probability (percents) max: ${tooltipValues.maxProbability} <div>
           <div> Probability (percents) min: ${tooltipValues.minProbability} <div>
           <div> Impact max: ${tooltipValues.maxImpact} <div>
           <div> Impact min ${tooltipValues.minImpact} <div>
           `
         )
             .style("left", (event.pageX) + "px")
             .style("top", (event.pageY - 28) + "px")
             .style("class", "content")

      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          div.transition()
              .duration(300)
              .style("opacity", 0);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to use the dots in the chart, I'd use the crossfilter objects to retrieve the data. (The model in our MVC is crossfilter, after all.)

So you can use `self.chart.dimension().top(Infinity)` to get all the raw rows of data which are currently filtered in. Note that [dimension.top](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_top) works differently from [group.all](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_all) in that it *does* observe its own filters. That's what you want here.

If you'd rather work with reduced (grouped) data, you'd have to create a separate dimension & group just to observe all the filters.

The important thing to notice here is that the selection is not particular to the brush or chart. Since the scatter plot already observes any filters on other charts, and you're interested in the brush on the scatter plot, the result is the same as the fully filtered set of rows in the crossfilter instance.

Answer (score 1):

You use `d` as an argument to the funcion. Depending on what your data looks like `d` will have different properties. For example `d.x` and `d.y`, or `d.impact` and `d.probability`

```
selection.on('mousemove', function(d){
    console.log('Hovering x at ' + d.x + ' and y at' + d.y);
    console.log(d);
});
```

Comment: I checked this option.
I see that d == 0

if you look at the arguments of the function - there will [0,0,0]

Comment: Probably because the selection is the brush, not the data points selected.